# Send input from component.html to component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm doing a search, and I'm receiving the value I need to search from the User on my `component.html`.

I'm sending the data to the `component.ts` like the code below.

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" #query (keyup.enter)="search(query.value)">
<a class="btn btn-light my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="search(query.value)">Buscar</a>
```

And in my `component.ts` I've the following code

```
search(query: string) {
    if (query !== '') {
        window.location.href = 'http://mydomain/result.html?name=' + query;
    }
}
```

My doubt is, why the `window.location.href` **always change** the `current URL` in the browser on `Firefox Developer Edition`, and only sometimes on `Google Chrome` and `Firefox Quantum`.

If I **click on the button**, It **always work** as expected, but if I **hit the enter**, It **work only sometimes** on the other 2 browsers, and I don't know why this is happening, can you guys help me with that?

- **EDIT**

I've noticed while debugging that, when I hit enter, it doesn't call the function `search`.

Comment: Maybe try to use (keyup)="search($event,query.value);
and on the function check if the event.keyCode == 13 (enter)
also I am not sure why ur working like this using #query and not just a simple model and use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, I've changed the `<input>` tag content and the tag `<a>` to `<button>`, like the code below

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" [(ngModel)]="query" name="busca">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-light my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="search()">Buscar</button>
```

And in my component I've the code below

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    query = ''; // Global variable in my component

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    search() {
        if (this.query !== '') {
            window.location.href = 'http://mydomain/result.html?name=' + this.query;
        }
    }
}
```

And on my `app.module.ts` I've added the following lines

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // Imported the FormsModule here

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyComponent } from './my/my.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule  // Added the FormsModule here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `(keyup.enter)` when in reality you want `(key.enter)`. Also, you don't need a reference `#query`. You could write input as:

```
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" (key.enter)="search($event)">
```

In the method use:

```
search(event: Event) {
    const query = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    if (query !== '') {
        window.location.href = 'http://mydomain/result.html?name=' + query;
    }
}
```

It seems that FireFox is catching `keyup` and not `enter`.